# Nil value on datetime_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When using <%= f.datetime_select :start %> for a "new" object form, how can you set the options to not select a date by default but rather a nil/null value? The field in the related model can optionally be null but by default the datetime_select control doesn't have a null option.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you want:

`f.datetime_select :start, :include_blank => true`

When `start` is nil, the fields will select the blank option. This also allows users to *not* enter a date.

See [the documentation for date_select](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#M001666) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the :prompt option.

from the Rails docs:

```
  # Generates a datetime select with a custom prompt. Use :prompt=>true for generic prompts.
  datetime_select("post", "written_on", :prompt => {:day => 'Choose day', :month => 'Choose month', :year => 'Choose year'})
  datetime_select("post", "written_on", :prompt => {:hour => true}) # generic prompt for hours
  datetime_select("post", "written_on", :prompt => true) # generic prompts for all
```

Comment: Extending the sample didn't seem to work. 
<%= f.datetime_select :start, :prompt => {:day => 'Choose day', :month => 'Choose month', :year => 'Choose year'} %>
Is there a syntax error here?

Comment: You could use the vanilla helper: <%= datetime_select :my_object, :start, :prompt => {:day => 'Choose day', :month => 'Choose month', :year => 'Choose year'} %>