# Leaving date/time blank in Rails datetime_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scaffolding

Is there an easy way to have the option to not specify a date or datetime in a Rails form that uses `datetime_select`, `date_select` or `time_select`? By default, the fields are set at the current date/time and there's no way to not choose a date/time.

Using Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the `include_blank` option: ([Nil value on datetime_select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559584/nil-value-on-datetime-select))

```
f.datetime_select :attr_name, include_blank: true
```